# Excluding duplicate data that is returned during an inner join

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am creating a video-game database. The tables that are relevant to the questions are:

```
1. game_data_primary (contains primary data such as release year and production company).

2. game_genre (contains game genre, a games can have multiple genres)

3. game_cast (again, a game can have many characters).
```

The video game detail page requires data across all the three tables. Hence, I have to INNER-JOIN the three tables, and fetch data. Now, here's the problem. There will be many rows that will be returned that'll contain duplicates. Here's one example

**Title Release Genre Character_name, picture_path**

GTA V, 2013, Action, Trevor, trevor_picture

GTA V, 2013, Action, Michael, michael_picture

GTA V, 2013, Action, Franklin, franklin_picture

GTA V, 2013, Open-World, Trevor, trevor_picture

...................................................

...................................................

Now, I need to create the video-game object to the ResultSet. The object has a List of cast models. Ideally, it should contain 3 entries (T,M, and F). But while mapping, I'll end-up adding many duplicate entries to my list of cast due the the nature of the result set in this case.

Is there a proper way to do this? I want an efficient way to create my video game model from the ResultSet.

Here's the mapping:

```
    List<GameCastModel> cast = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> genres = new ArrayList<>();
    GameInfoModelBuilder gameInfoBuilder = GameInfoModelBuilder.builder();
    for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
        cast.add(MovieCastModel.builder().name(String.valueOf(row.get("name")))
                .character_name(String.valueOf(row.get("character_name")))
                .profile_path(String.valueOf(row.get("profile_path"))).build());
        genres.add(CinestopConstants.GENRE_MAP.get(String.valueOf(row.get("genre_id"))));
        gameInfoBuilder.title(row.get("title").toString())
                .budget(String.format("%.2f",
                        ((Double) (Double.parseDouble(row.get("budget").toString()) / 1000000))))
            .plot(row.get("plot").toString())
                .release(row.get("release_date").toString())
                .revenue(String.format("%.2f",
                        ((Double) (Double.parseDouble(row.get("revenue").toString()) / 1000000))))
                .runtime(row.get("runtime").toString()).tagline(row.get("tagline").toString())
                .language(row.get("language").toString())
                ;
    }

    gameInfoBuilder.genre(genres);
    gameInfoBuilder.cast(cast);
```

Comment: Please add create table and insert query and also add expected result based your insert query.

Comment: How about adding distinct clause in your select query like **select distinct * from ...**

Comment: I don't think that'd help. There'll still be multiple entries, which is perfectly fine. I just want to avoid adding multiple objects to my list while mapping.

Comment: Could you please show how you map ?

Comment: I have it in the question now.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra I have it in the question now.

Comment: You can use Set instead of List and override equals and hashcode method for Object which you want to add into Set

Comment: I think I got that. I am using a HashSet that keeps track of all the characters that I have added (using a unique character id). Before adding a cast to my list, I check if the cast already contains that character or not. I wonder how this additional code will affect the latency though...